# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Doesn't Call Existing Script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

### Background

I have a client-side button click that triggers a server-side function. Before the server side function is called, a loading panel is displayed (div).

The loading panel needs to be removed once the server-side function has completed.

### My Solution

After the server-side function is complete I will call a JavaScript function that will remove the div. So as a test i'm calling an alert script. I'm trying to do this from the master page.

### *Client-Side Code*

My PopUp Function

```
    <script>
        function PopUp() {
        debugger;
        alert('TEST');
        }
     </script>
```

My Script Manager

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

### *Server-Side Code*

My Call after server side functions have completed.

```
//Add the script  after <form> tag
   bool isClientScriptBlockRegistered = ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ShowStatus");
   if (!isClientScriptBlockRegistered)
   {
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "PopUp();", true);
   }
```

### Problem

My script isn't called by the server. No alert window is created. When I try to do this from any page other that the master page it works. However on the master page it does not.

### Questions

Is there something I'm missing?

Does there need to be a callback or some kind of refreshing of the page for the alert to appear, or can the server just call the script without any action from the client?

Comment: Do you see "ShowStatus" script in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Nope, I see no change to the HTML.

Comment: So, this is the problem: the script is not really registered in the page. Is ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock line executed?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Yes ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock line is run everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "PopUp();", true);
```

into

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "setTimeout(function () {  PopUp(); }, 10);", true);
```

or into

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "PopUp();", true);
```

`RegisterClientScriptBlock` adds the JavaScript code at the top of the page just after the ViewState tag while `RegisterClientScriptBlock` adds it to the bottom. So if you use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and your `PopUp()` is somewhere lower on the page you'll get an error.

Or by setting a `setTimeout` you ensure that all the contents is generated and then `PopUp()` will also be found even is the script block is at the top.